# Converting VB to c# not compiling

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert :

```
Public Event GoogleAPIRequestCompleted(Status As HttpStatusCode, Response As String)


Private Sub OnGoogleAPIRequestCompleted(Status As HttpStatusCode, Response As String)
    If p_SynchronizationContext IsNot Nothing Then
        p_SynchronizationContext.Send(New Threading.SendOrPostCallback(Sub() RaiseEvent GoogleAPIRequestCompleted(Status, Response)), Nothing)
    Else
        RaiseEvent GoogleAPIRequestCompleted(Status, Response)
    End If
End Sub
```

to C# but most online converter is either throwing an error or giving me in accurate convertion.

whats the equivalent of the above code in C#?

Online converter result:

```
internal partial class SurroundingClass
{
    public event GoogleAPIRequestCompletedEventHandler GoogleAPIRequestCompleted;

    public delegate void GoogleAPIRequestCompletedEventHandler(HttpStatusCode Status, string Response);

    private void OnGoogleAPIRequestCompleted(HttpStatusCode Status, string Response)
    {
        if (p_SynchronizationContext is object)
        {
            p_SynchronizationContext.Send(new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(() => GoogleAPIRequestCompleted?.Invoke(Status, Response)), default);
        }
        else
        {
            GoogleAPIRequestCompleted?.Invoke(Status, Response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What do online converters give you. I've got a feeling that you won't be able to convert just this on it's own.

Comment: What is the compiler error it's giving?

Comment: Error CS1593 Delegate 'SendOrPostCallback' does not take 0 arguments

Comment: `p_SynchronizationContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(_ => GoogleAPIRequestCompleted?.Invoke(Status, Response)), default)`, or alternatively just `p_SynchronizationContext.Send(_ => GoogleAPIRequestCompleted?.Invoke(Status, Response), null)`

Answer (score 0):

code converting could be tricky and not working anytime. I would suggest the code converter from telerik, I have good results with it.

Link: [Converter](https://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: I have had luck with it but just not this particular functionality.